# iPhone opengl es alpha-blending. I have black color in edge

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, alphablending

I am developing iPhone game. I have the below Source image to draw it to the background. The Source image has alpha 0x00 and gradation around edge and the background's alpha is 0xff. When I draw the source image to the background, I have black color like you could see the Result image. I am using OpenGL ES glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) method. I have changed every possible arguments, but every time it is not moved.

Why do I have the black color in the edge of the source image? What is the problem? Does not every games in iphone use gradation?

Do I need to make the source image with out gradation?

Does anyone know the solution?

Source image :

[image]

Result image :

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does your image have pre-multiplied alpha?  Then you should be using

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

[Here](http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#%5B%5BPremultiplied%20alpha%5D%5D) is some explanations of what it is.

**Note:** I rewrote the answer after doing some research.  The article **rotoglup** mentioned has some insight on what's going on and it makes more sense then my original formula.  I also tried to see what other people are using in their code and it looks like this formula is the most used one.  It's amazing how such a basic thing in 3D graphics as alpha blending can be so controversial and everyone seems to reinvent the wheel and come up with their own solutions.

Comment: Agreed, this looks like a typical double multiplication of alpha.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ONE, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA ?

Comment: Here is an article that can be another source of explanations : http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#%5B%5BPremultiplied%20alpha%5D%5D

Comment: @rotoglup: Maybe you're right.  I think I've used this one in the past, but I don't have the code to check it out right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the view on which you are drawing is opaque or not. set opaque property to false

Comment: This is in OpenGL, not UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can occur is if you haven't correctly set your glTexParameteri for minification and magnification filters correctly, along with your clamp method. See Adam Redwood's comment [here](http://www.monkeycoder.co.nz/Community/posts.php?topic=1559). Note issues of power-of-two textures, texture boundaries etc. may also come into play.

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
```