# Android OpenGL ES pixilation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

I have an image that is resized within the app however it looks pretty terrible depending on what it has been scaled to and I dont know how to fix this...

[image]

Making the image bigger is not the solution and I have already set the mag and min filters as follows...

```
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
```

Does anyone know how I can avoid this?

EDIT: Also why is there a black outline around this as there is no border around it in Photoshop, the background is transparent.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange black borders are normally a sign of using premultiplied alpha when the rendering library isn't expecting it, or vice versa.

See this question: [iPhone opengl es alpha-blending. I have black color in edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771224/iphone-opengl-es-alpha-blending-i-have-black-color-in-edge)

It'll also make the antialiasing go funny which will make your image look strangely pixelated, so *if* that's the problem, it could well fix that as well.